# get clicked / currently active ui element oculus OVR unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, raycasting, oculus

I have been trying to get the UI dropdown element to work with the oculus rift. 
I have converted the Canvas, and Eventsystem to work with the OVR classes from oculus. At this moment all the ui elements work except the DropDown element.

After doing some research i found that the Dropdown element dynamically creates the list of options resulting that these elements cant be intersected by the OVRRaycaster. So i tried the following code, to update the elements if they change dynamically:

```
void Update () 
{
    var found = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<GraphicRaycaster>();
    foreach (var gr in found) {
    var ovr = gr.GetComponent<OVRRaycaster>();
        if (ovr == null) {
            gr.enabled = false;
            ovr = gr.gameObject.AddComponent<OVRRaycaster>();
            ovr.sortOrder = 20;
        }
    }
}
```

sadly this broke all the ui elements in the progress (and didnt fix the dropdown element). So i thought why not get the current element that i am hovering over and apply the same code. See if it makes a difference. So i tried to get the following function from the Oculus documentation:

```
OVRRaycaster.OnPointerEnter ( PointerEventData e )
```

but this line gives me the following error:

> 'PointerEventData' is a type, which is not valid in the given context [Assembly-CSharp]

So i have two questions actually:

1. How to get the current ui element (hovering or clicked)
2. How do i get the UI Dropdown element to work with the Oculus rift (OVRRayCaster)

If something is unclear pls let me know so i can clarify.